# How can I save a second row of UIPickerView to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults, rows

I have pickerView with two rows and I need to save position of both to NSUserDefaults. I have successful saved first row with this code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {    
    NSInteger selectedRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"picker"];
}
```

And I don't get how to add a second one.

With this code I bring back the position:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[picker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"picker"] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[picker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"picker"] inComponent:1 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
             inComponent:(NSInteger)component {    
    NSInteger selectedRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:component];
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"picker%d", component];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:key];
}
```

and this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [picker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"picker0"] 
        inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [picker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"picker1"] 
        inComponent:1 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Not working :( Log display same result even I choose from different rows

Comment: Really? Look carefully at the differences in what I suggested compared to your original code. Note that in the first function, you have to fetch the selected row in the correct component. Then a key is constructed whose value is specific to the component, e.g. picker0. In the second function, those keys are used explicitly to retrieve the correct values. Now, I didn't build or run this code, but this all looks pretty simple (to me), so if there is an issue now, I am not seeing it! :-) Have you stepped through this code in the debugger?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I thought it might. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add them with separate keys.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:   (NSInteger)component {    
NSInteger selectedRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"pickerRow1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"pickerRow2"];
}
```